# How to create a carousel view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, carousel

I was wondering if anyone could tell me where I can get an updated tutorial on how to make a carousel view.

I have searched all over and I cannot find something that is not for Swift UI or is outdated with XIB files.

Here is something along the lines of which I want to create:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alirezat775/CarouselView/master/assets/demo.gif

**Edit:**

I found a cool one here :

https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/create-a-horizontal-paging-uiscrollview-with-uipagecontrol-swift-4-xcode-9-a3dddc845e92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all who helped I think that I have found a cool one here: https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/create-a-horizontal-paging-uiscrollview-with-uipagecontrol-swift-4-xcode-9-a3dddc845e92

hope this helps someone else as it has helped me!

Answer (score 5):

You can look into following library. I have previously used it and it work well.

[UPCarouselFlowLayout](https://github.com/ink-spot/UPCarouselFlowLayout)

[image: Demo]

Comment: hey man, Thank you for your reply. I continued searching and I think I have found another cool option here: https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/create-a-horizontal-paging-uiscrollview-with-uipagecontrol-swift-4-xcode-9-a3dddc845e92